# Unit testing classes in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a few classes in Python that I would like to unit test, each of them has an `__init__()` method that instantiates a dictionary and have a method that depending on the arguments passed to them return either an error or the required return value. My question is as the dictionary is hardcoded in, am I ok to just unittest with just those values? Or should I consider that these values could be changed in the future? As far as I know only values will be added to them. If this is the case, would I need to use mock? As how would I override instantiation. An example of one class is like follows:

```
class TeamLocation:

    def __init__(self):
        self._types_location = {
            "New York": {
                "id": 1,
                "team_id": 1

            },
            "LA": {
                "id": 2,
                "team_id": 2
            }
        }

    def get_user_team_id(self, location):
        team_id_item = self._types_location.get(location, None)
        if not team_id_item:
            raise CityNotSupportedException(f"Location: {location} does not exist.")
        return team_id_item["team_id"]

def test_team_location_ok():

    team_location = TeamLocation()
    assert team_location.get_user_team_id('New York') == 1


def test_team_location_not_ok():

    team_location = TeamLocation()
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as excinfo:
        team_location.get_user_team_id('Boston')
    assert excinfo.value.message == 'Location: Boston does not exist.'
```

Comment: If this is your code, then `self._types_location` is hard coded in the `__init__()` method as you say. You should test for exactly that. If someone updates your code later, they should update the tests at the same time.

Comment: @quamrana Makes sense, is it worth making a test to evaluate the dictionary after instantiation?

Comment: Yes, as I said above: "`You should test for exactly that`". Instantiate your class and test the contents of the `dict`.